# send parameters via bluetooth to nonstandard device

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bluetooth

i trying to send values to cellocator device

the server seems to have empty services

i dont understand how to send values

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: No Services found in device.

```
    navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
        acceptAllDevices: true, 
    })
    .then(device => {
        return device.gatt.connect(); 
    })
    .then(server => {
        
        let services = server.getPrimaryServices() 
   })

    .catch(error => {
        console.error(`Error opening  device: ${error}`);
    });
```

Comment: This error you are showing "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: No Services found in device" means that the device you are trying to connect doesn't have any Bluetooth services that can be discovered or is possible too an issue in the way the discovery is being done. So try to check check Device Compatibility and also you can Check Bluetooth Permissions

Answer (score 0):

First read the comment I made, after you can try it:

Instead of using acceptAllDevices: true, try to specify the UUIDs of the services you are interested in.

```
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
    filters: [{
        services: ['service_uuid'] // Replace 'service_uuid' with your device's service UUID
    }]
})
.then(device => {
    return device.gatt.connect(); 
})
.then(server => {
    return server.getPrimaryServices(); // Get specific services
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(`Error: ${error}`);
});
```

You need to know the UUIDs of your services cellocator. This information is provided in the device's documentation.

Comment: when i use the app serial bluetooth terminal the app read the value service_uuid from the device, i dont need to know it 
how to read it with js?

Comment: Instead of specifying a service UUID, you can list all available devices. Users can then select the device they want to connect to.   After connecting to a device, you can discover all its services and characteristics. This way, you can interact with the device without knowing the UUIDs beforehand.